# Angular Material body height 100%

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I'm currently using angular with material in a project, but I'm having a problem with the body size of the page. In all my screens there is a grey bar at the bottom as the images show:

[log-in screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zUtz.jpg)

[pedidos screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6G7mW.png)

Since I want to use an image in the background of the first image, that bar proved to be a problem.
That's my styles.css:

```
html, body { 
    margin: 0;
    height: 100% !important; 
}

.body { 
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    background-color:#fafafa;
}

.body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

There's a way to remove that bar?

Comment: Try this answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54443350/how-to-set-background-image-in-div-element-in-angular-material-app/54445197

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!